# How to comprehend the flow of this assembly code

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering, objdump

I can' t understand how this works.
Here's a part of main() program disassembled by objdump and written in intel notation

```
0000000000000530 <main>:
530:    lea    rdx,[rip+0x37d]        # 8b4 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
537:    mov    DWORD PTR [rsp-0xc],0x0
53f:    movabs r10,0xedd5a792ef95fa9e 
549:    mov    r9d,0xffffffcc
54f:    nop
550:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rsp-0xc]
554:    cmp    eax,0xd
557:    ja     57c <main+0x4c>
559:   movsxd rax,DWORD PTR [rdx+rax*4]
55d:    add    rax,rdx
560:    jmp    rax
```

The `rodata` section dump:

```
.rodata 
 08b0 01000200 ecfdffff d4fdffff bcfdffff  ................
 08c0 9cfdffff 7cfdffff 6cfdffff 4cfdffff  ....|...l...L...
 08d0 3cfdffff 2cfdffff 0cfdffff ecfcffff  <...,...........
 08e0 d4fcffff b4fcffff 0cfeffff           ............
```

In 530, rip is [537] so [rdx] = [537 + 37d] = 8b4.
First question is the value of rdx is how large? Is the valueis ec, or ecfdffff or something else? If it has DWORD, I can understand that has 'ecfdffff' (even this is wrong too?:() but this program don't declare it. How can I judge the value?

Then the program continues.
In 559, rax is first appeared.
The second question is this rax can interpret as a part of eax and in this time is the rax = 0? If rax is 0, in 559 means rax = DWORD[rdx] and the value of rax become ecfdffff and next [55d] do rax += rdx, and I think this value can't jamp. There must be something wrong, so tell me where, or how i make any wrongs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'll diverge from what Peter discussed (he provides good information) and get to the heart of some issues I think are causing you problems. When I first glanced at this question I assumed that the code was likely compiler generated and the `jmp rax` was likely the result of some control flow statement. The most likely way to generate such a code sequence is via a *C* [`switch`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch). It isn't uncommon for a `switch` statement to be made of a jump table to say what code should execute depending on the control variable. As an example: the control variable for `switch(a)` is `a`.

This all made sense to me, and I wrote up a number of comments (now deleted) that ultimately resulted in bizarre memory addresses that `jmp rax` would go to. I had errands to run but when I returned I had the aha moment that you may have had the same confusion I did. This output from `objdump` using the `-s` option appeared as:

> ```
> .rodata 
>  08b0 01000200 ecfdffff d4fdffff bcfdffff  ................
>  08c0 9cfdffff 7cfdffff 6cfdffff 4cfdffff  ....|...l...L...
>  08d0 3cfdffff 2cfdffff 0cfdffff ecfcffff  <...,...........
>  08e0 d4fcffff b4fcffff 0cfeffff           ............
> ```

One of your questions seems to be about what values get loaded here. I never used the `-s` option to look at data in the sections and was unaware that although the dump splits the data out in groups of 4 bytes (32-bit values) they are shown in byte order as it appears in memory. I had at first assumed the output was displaying these values from Most Significant Byte to Least significant byte and `objdump -s` had done the conversion. That is not the case.

You have to manually reverse the bytes of each group of 4 bytes to get the real value that would be read from memory into a register.

`ecfdffff` in the output actually means `ec fd ff ff`. As a DWORD value (32-bit) you need to reverse the bytes to get the HEX value as you would expect when loaded from memory. `ec fd ff ff` reversed would be `ff ff fd ec` or the 32-bit value `0xfffffdec`. Once you realize that then this makes a lot more sense. If you make this same adjustment for all the data in that table you'd get:

> ```
> .rodata 
>  08b0: 0x00020001 0xfffffdec 0xfffffdd4 0xfffffdbc
>  08c0: 0xfffffd9c 0xfffffd7c 0xfffffd6c 0xfffffd4c
>  08d0: 0xfffffd3c 0xfffffd2c 0xfffffd0c 0xfffffcec
>  08e0: 0xfffffcd4 0xfffffcb4 0xfffffe0c
> ```

Now if we look at the code you have it starts with:

```
530:    lea    rdx,[rip+0x37d]        # 8b4 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
```

This doesn't load data from memory, it is computing the effective address of some data and places the address in *RDX*. The disassembly from OBJDUMP is displaying the code and data with the view that it is loaded in memory starting at 0x000000000000. When it is loaded into memory it may be placed at some other address. GCC in this case is producing position independent code (PIC). It is generated in such a way that the first byte of the program can start at an arbitrary address in memory.

The `# 8b4` comment is the part we are concerned about (you can ignore the information after that). The disassembly is saying if the program was loaded at 0x0000000000000000 then the value loaded into *RDX* would be 0x8b4. How was that arrived at? This instruction starts at 0x530 but with RIP relative addressing the RIP (instruction pointer) is relative to the address just after the current instruction. The address the disassembler used was 0x537 (the byte after the current instruction is the address of the first byte of the next instruction). The instruction adds 0x37d to RIP and gets 0x537+0x37d=0x8b4. The address 0x8b4 happens to be in the `.rodata` section which you are given a dump of (as discussed above).

We now know that RDX contains the base of some data. The `jmp rax` suggests this is likely going to be a table of 32-bit values that are used to determine what memory location to jump to depending on the value in the control variable of a `switch` statement.

This statement appears to be storing the value 0 as a 32-bit value on the stack.

```
537:    mov    DWORD PTR [rsp-0xc],0x0
```

These appear to be variables that the compiler chose to store in registers (rather than memory).

```
53f:    movabs r10,0xedd5a792ef95fa9e 
549:    mov    r9d,0xffffffcc
```

*R10* is being loaded with the 64-bit value 0xedd5a792ef95fa9e. *R9D* is the lower 32-bits of the 64-bit *R9* register.The value 0xffffffcc is being loaded into the lower 32-bits of *R9* but there is something else occurring. In 64-bit mode if the destination of an instruction is a 32-bit register the **CPU automatically zero extends the value into the upper 32-bits of the register**. The CPU is guaranteeing us that the upper 32-bits are zeroed.

This is a `NOP` and doesn't do anything except align the next instruction to memory address 0x550. 0x550 is a value that is 16-byte aligned. This has some value and may hint that the instruction at 0x550 may be the first instruction at the top of a loop. An optimizer may place `NOP`s into the code to align the first instruction at the top of a loop to a 16-byte aligned address in memory for performance reasons:

```
54f:    nop
```

Earlier the 32-bit stack based variable at `rsp-0xc` was set to zero. This reads the value 0 from memory as a 32-bit value and stores it in *EAX*. Since *EAX* is a 32-bit register being used as the destination for the instruction the CPU automatically filled the upper 32-bits of *RAX* to 0. So all of *RAX* is zero.

```
550:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rsp-0xc]
```

*EAX* is now being compared to 0xd. If it is above (`ja`) it goes to the instruction at 0x57c.

```
554:    cmp    eax,0xd
557:    ja     57c <main+0x4c>
```

We then have this instruction:

```
559:   movsxd rax,DWORD PTR [rdx+rax*4]
```

The [`movsxd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movsx:movsxd) is an instruction that will take a 32-bit source operand (in this case the 32-bit value at memory address `RDX+RAX*4`) load it into the bottom 32-bits of *RAX* and then sign extend the value into the upper 32-bits of *RAX*. Effectively if the 32-bit value is negative (the most significant bit is 1) the upper 32-bits of *RAX* will be set to 1. If the 32-bit value is not negative the upper 32-bits of *RAX* will be set to 0.

When this code is first encountered *RDX* contains the base of some table at 0x8b4 from the beginning of the program loaded in memory. *RAX* is set to 0. Effectively the first 32-bits in the table are copied to *RAX* and sign extended. As seen earlier the value at offset 0xb84 is 0xfffffdec. That 32-bit value is negative so *RAX* contains 0xfffffffffffffdec.

Now to the meat of the situation:

```
55d:    add    rax,rdx
560:    jmp    rax
```

*RDX* still holds the address to the beginning of a table in memory. *RAX* is being added to that value and stored back in *RAX* (*RAX* = *RAX*+*RDX*). We then JMP to the address stored in *RAX*. So this code all seems to suggest we have a JUMP table with 32-bit values that we are using to determine where we should go. So then the obvious question. What are the 32-bit values in the table? The 32-bit values are the difference between the beginning of the table and the address of the instruction we want to jump to.

We know the table is 0x8b4 from the location our program is loaded in memory. The *C* compiler told the linker to compute the difference between 0x8b4 and the address where the instruction we want to execute resides. If the program had been loaded into memory at 0x0000000000000000 (hypothetically), *RAX* = *RAX*+*RDX* would have resulted in *RAX* being 0xfffffffffffffdec + 0x8b4 = 0x00000000000006a0. We then use `jmp rax` to jump to 0x6a0. You didn't show the entire dump of memory but there is going to be code at 0x6a0 that will execute when the value passed to the `switch` statement is 0. Each 32-bit value in the JUMP table will be a similar offset to the code that will execute depending on the control variable in the `switch` statement. If we add 0x8b4 to all the entries in the table we get:

> ```
>  08b0:            0x000006a0 0x00000688 0x00000670
>  08c0: 0x00000650 0x00000630 0x00000620 0x00000600
>  08d0: 0x000005F0 0x000005e0 0x000005c0 0x000005a0
>  08e0: 0x00000588 0x00000568 0x000006c0
> ```

You should find that in the code you haven't provided us that these addresses coincide with code that appears after the `jmp rax`.

Given that the memory address 0x550 was aligned, I have a hunch that this `switch` statement is inside a loop that keeps executing as some kind of [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) until the proper conditions are met for it to exit. Likely the value of the control variable used for the `switch` statement is changed by the code in the `switch` statement itself. Each time the `switch` statement is run the control variable has a different value and will do something different.

The control variable for the `switch` statement was originally checked for the value being above 0x0d (13). The table starting at 0x8b4 in the `.rodata` section has 14 entries. One can assume the `switch` statement probably has 14 different states (cases).

Comment: I'm grateful to you to detailed answer!
The answer is so easy for me to understand.
I don't have and know about other part of program without all of main() section and .rodata section, but this assembly is exactly explained as a part of program when the proper comandline argument is entered, return 0, if it wasn't proper argument, return 1.

Answer (score 2):

> but this program don't declare it

You're looking at disassembly of machine code + data.  It's all just bytes in memory.  Any labels the disassembler does manage to show are ones that got left in the executable's symbol table.  They're irrelevant to how the CPU runs the machine code.

(The ELF program headers tell the OS's program loader how to map it into memory, and where to jump to as an entry point.  This has nothing to do with symbols, unless a shared library references some globals or functions defined in the executable.)

You can single-step the code in GDB and watch register values change.

---

> In 559, `rax` is first appeared.

EAX is the low 32 bits of RAX.  Writing to EAX zero-extends into RAX implicitly.  From `mov    DWORD PTR [rsp-0xc],0x0` and the later reload, we know that RAX=0.

**This must have been un-optimized compiler output (or `volatile int idx = 0;` to defeat constant propagation)**, otherwise it would know at compile time that RAX=0 and could optimize away everything else.

---

`lea    rdx,[rip+0x37d]        # 8b4`

A RIP-relative LEA puts the *address* of static into a register.  It's not a load from memory.  (That happens later when `movsxd` with an indexed addressing mode uses RDX as the base address.)

The disassembler worked out the address for you; it's `RDX = 0x8b4`.  (Relative to the start of the file; when actually running the program would be mapped at a virtual address like `0x55555...000`)

---

```
554:    cmp    eax,0xd
557:    ja     57c <main+0x4c>
559:   movsxd rax,DWORD PTR [rdx+rax*4]
55d:    add    rax,rdx
560:    jmp    rax
```

This is a jump table.  First it checks for an out-of-bounds index with `cmp eax,0xd`, then it indexes a table of 32-bit signed offsets using EAX (`movsxd` with an addressing mode that scales RAX by 4), and adds that to the base address of the table to get a jump target.

GCC *could* just make a jump table of 64-bit absolute pointers, but chooses not to so that `.rodata` is position-independent as well and doesn't need load-time fixups in a PIE executable.  (Even though Linux does support doing that.)  See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84011 where this is discussed (although the main focus of that bug is that gcc `-fPIE` can't turn a switch into a table lookup of string addresses, and actually still uses a jump table)

**The jump-offset table address is in RDX**, this is what was set up with the earlier LEA.

Comment: I'm grateful to your answer!
I don't have all of the program so I may not use gdb.
But gdb may very useful tool to study assembly, so I will try learn gdb!

Comment: @hahn: In real life you never have just `objdump` output without the binary, because you had to use `objdump` yourself *on* the binary.  So you can always `gdb` it.  (If it's potentially malware, preferably inside a VM, and/or be careful to just single step, and not past any `syscall` or `int 0x80` instructions.)  Or `set $pc = 0x123456` and set registers however you want, to start single-stepping a piece of code you're curious about.  (Although normally easier to copy/paste asm text into a file and assemble it, except here where there's associated data.)